# Publishing an internal NuGet Package with Automatic Versioning best practice

Tags: azure-devops, versioning

So we are experimenting with automating our build processes and NuGet publishing for some of our internal dlls and trying to figure out what would be best practice for the VSTS Automatic versioning.

I've been reading this article ([Versioning Nuget Packages CD](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/05/03/versioning-nuget-packages-cd-1/)) which talks about the SemVar for automatic versioning which is fine but I'm wondering if there is a way we can automate the versioning down to just a Major.Minor.Patch schema. My gut tells me this isn't reasonable, I mean how could the process know whether you are publishing a Major, Minor, or Patch but maybe there isn't something I am thinking of.

Either way, any tips on best practice for versioning would be great. I'm thinking there has to be a way at the very least for us to just edit the Assembly Info before we commit to master and trigger the Build process to then package it all up and acquire that new version. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publishing nuget package version authomcatically and increase major/minor/patch correspondingly, two suggested way is **using GitFlow branching module with GitVersion** and **calculating the updated version manually**.

#### Option 1: using GitFlow branching module with Gitversion

If you manage manging your source code in git repo, you can use [GitFlow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html) as the branching module. Then you can use [GitVersion](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gittools.gitversion) task in your build/release definition, it will provider the increment version.

More details, you can refer [Versioning NuGet packages in a continuous delivery world: part 3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/05/26/versioning-nuget-packages-cd-3/).

#### Option 2: calculate the updated version manually

You can define how to update major, minor and patch as the way you need to update. You can achieve it by adding a PowerShell task:

Add a variable (such as `version`) in Variables Tab -> Get current version -> set the variable `version` with the value of the current version -> define the way how to update the version (such as changed file A for the build commit/changeset, then update minor) -> update variable `version`'s value with the updated version.

In the Nuget pack step, specify the package version for the variable `version`'s value. Then publish the package.

More details, you can refer Better selection of version numbers in the article [Versioning NuGet packages in a continuous delivery world: part 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/05/18/versioning-nuget-packages-cd-2).